# Getting null values with data in list of collection of object

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to add few employee objects inside the list named collectionofEmployees here.I am able to add the data but i am getting first record for custom object attributes as nulls.The data is getting inserted after that properly.

Here is my controller.

```
@RestController
public class CustomController {

@Autowired
Employees collectionofEmployees;

@RequestMapping("/add")
public Employees add() {
    
    collectionofEmployees.add(new Employee(1,"XYZ"));
    collectionofEmployees.add(new Employee(3, "VTY"));
    return collectionofEmployees;

}
```

Here is my Employees Model class which contains list of employee

```
@Component
public class Employees {

@Autowired
private List<Employee>employees;

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
public Employees(List<Employee> employees) {
    super();
    this.employees = employees;
}


public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}


public void add(Employee employee)
{        
         this.employees.add(employee);
    
}
```

Here is my employee class

```
@Component
public class Employee {

private Integer id;
private String name;
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}   
public Employee() {
    super();
}


public Employee(Integer id, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}


public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

The output i am getting is as {"employees":[{"id":null,"name":null},{"id":1,"name":"XYZ"},{"id":3,"name":"VTY"}]}

Help would be appreciated alot:)I want to avoid nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `@Component` from Employee class. It is initialized by Spring and injected to your

```
@Autowired
private List<Employee>employees
```

Comment: @Y N It doesn't run in that case

Comment: @YN is correct, don't annotate your model classes with `@Component`. Spring components instantiated by spring and are singletons by default. This is not what you want for your data model. You can simply initialize your `Employees` instance in your component, you don't need to inject it.

Comment: List<Employee>collectionofEmployess=new ArrayList<Employee>();
 
    @RequestMapping("/hello")

 public void add() {
  
  collectionofEmployess.add(new Employee(1,"XYZ"));
  collectionofEmployess.add(new Employee(3, "VTY"));
  
  System.out.println(collectionofEmployess);

 }

Comment: @HopeyOne do you mean like way i mentioned above?I thought its not good habit to instantiate objects like this manually.I am still new to spring and learning.Correct me if i am wrong,you mean there is no point of injecting through spring if we are adding a list of custom objects for our data model as injections is only  good in case single objects?

Comment: @Ashish34630 If you want to manage objects yourself you don't need ask Spring to manage them.

With ```@Component``` you ask Spring to create object for you.

```@Autowired``` insructs Spring find object with specified type and set where annotation placed.
Setting ```@Autowired``` at collection you ask Spring to create specified collection with object of specified type already known to Spring.

So my bad I've not said to remove ```@Autowired``` from ```List<Employee>```.

Answer (score 0):

As i still dont know how to avoid nulls at time of intialisation done by spring,for temporary purpose i have added collectionofEmployees.getEmployees().remove(0) under add method which removes the nulls from the input.